# How to handle DML operations in Apache Storm Topology

Tags: solr, apache-storm

In my Architecture, DML commands are queued in to Kafka. Storm topology comprises of single Spout and 3 Solr Bolts. The DML commands get distributed among these 3 Bolts.

My Problem is how to handle if the order of commands get shuffled by Solr Bolts. For ex., the sequence of commands are

1. Insert record A with value 50.
2. Insert record B with value x.
3. Update record A to value 20.
4. Insert record C with value y.
5. Update record A to value 100.
   and so on

In the above case, what if the command 5 get executed by a Bolt before command 3 getting executed by other Bolt?  This can happen if Bolt 3 first picks and executes the 5th command before Bolt 2 executes the command 3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you have single spout (with dop=1) and a single bolt (with dop=3) that get the data from spout via shuffle grouping. If the dependent command are shuffled to different bolt-executors, there is no way to get the executed in correct order.

However, if you have a series of commands that depends on each other, you can use fieldsGrouping to ensure that all command go to the same executor. For this case, the order is guaranteed to be preserved. To accomplish this, you just add an attribute to the spout output tuples (a counter), and field-group on this attribute. Furthermore, for consecutive dependent commands, you do not modify the counter. If a series of dependent command is finished, you increase the counter by one (this ensure, that different command series are processed by different bolt-executors, ie, load balancing). The tricky part is to know, when a series of dependent commands is finished I guess. Hope this helps.